# Unable to install git

Tags: linux, git, github, git-svn

I ran the following commands on linux mint 12 lisa:

```
1). sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
2). sudo apt-get update
3). sudo apt-get install git
```

I am getting the following error on running 3. That is, installing git:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list file contains the following content:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ lisa main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ oneiric free non-free

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu oneiric-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu oneiric-getdeb games
```

sudo apt-get upgrade shows the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: @vidit What does sudo apt-get upgrade do?

Comment: ignore the comment, that was useless.

Comment: I think it is `git-core`, so all together should be: `apt-get install git-core`

Comment: @fedorqui When I install git-core. Then also I get the error: Unable to locate package git-core

Comment: Would http://superuser.com/q/587052/141 help?

Comment: @VonC sudo aptitude install git gives Couldn't find any package matching "git", and more than 40 packages contain "git" in their description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install aptitude first.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then install git using the command

```
sudo aptitude install git
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem and solved it by running the update and upgrade at the same on one command line.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

after that I normally installed git with :

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all but this works for me

In Terminal

1. ```
   $ software-properties-gtk
   ```
2. In Ubuntu, `Software/Download_From_internet`, enable all of the check marks
3. ```
   $ sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```
4. ```
   $ sudo aptitude install git
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, but solved by update then upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```